# Git: Is there a way to push a commit only held by a tag, without pushing the tag?

Tags: git, git-push, git-tag

#### Scenario:

1. Create a `tmp` branch
2. Commit some temporary changes
3. Tag the commit `tmptag`

   > ```
   > x-x-x-y-y  <- master
   >      \
   >       z  <- tmp [tmptag]
   > ```
4. Delete the `tmp` branch

   > ```
   > x-x-x-y-y  <- master
   >      \
   >       z  <- [tmptag]
   > ```

Now I have a commit, `z` that is being held only by a tag `tmptag`.

I understand that if you push `tmptag` to the remote (either by name or by pushing all tags), commit `z` will also be pushed.

#### Questions:

1. Are there any other commands that will push `z` to the remote?
2. Also, if specifically I push all branches, `z` will *not* be pushed, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, anything that says *ask the other Git to please set some name to point to the commit whose ID is `z`* will transfer commit `z`.  For instance:

   ```
   git push $(git rev-parse tmptag^{}):refs/heads/newbranch
   ```

   would ask the other Git to create branch `newbranch` pointing to the tagged commit.  (The `^{}` suffix is required if and only if `tmptag` is an annotated tag.)  You could also use the raw hash ID, and something other than a branch name, provided the other Git allows you to push to that reference.
2. Correct: since `z` is not reachable from a branch name, it will (at least normally<sup>1</sup>) not get sent.

---

<sup>1</sup>Each Git transport is responsible for collecting objects to send and sending them, and if some transport is weird or careless or something, it could collect up commit `z` and send it.  The built in push transports (generally invoking `git send-pack` with `--thin`) won't do that, but it's interesting to consider a case where `z` is a base object in a pack, and some deltified object in the same pack also needs to be sent.

Comment: By the way - if a commit did get pushed without having a branch/tag attached, would it become an immediate orphan on the remote?

Comment: It would become a gc candidate, yes. It's not clear to me precisely when a `git repack` would get rid of it: that code is full of oddball exceptions, including `.keep` files for packs.